# Glassfish Bean Validation weird error

Tags: glassfish, bean-validation, corba

I am using bean validation in my application. When there is no constraint validation errors everything works nicely. Every time there is a validation error, Glassfish throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.groups.Default: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: osgi
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:325)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:628)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.RepIdDelegator.getClassFromType(RepIdDelegator.java:169)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readClass(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1439)
```

The bean-validation.jar is present in glassfish/modules folder. The startup doesn't throw any exceptions regarding validation.

PS. Note that we are using remote beans with CORBA.

Reproducable on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and 3.1.1.

Comment: I traced this problem to serialization of the ConstraintValidationException through CORBA. Somehow the bean-validation module is not loaded properly with osgi and the javax.validation.groups.Default class is missing. I made a quick workaround so that the ConstraintValidationException is intercepted and never sent through CORBA. Instead the validation error information is gathered in a custom Exception class that can be actually serialized through the services.

Comment: Can you provide some informations how you intercept the message since I have the same error. Using my dao I know when violations could occur but using interceptor would be nicer.

Comment: I am no longer able to access or provide the code I used but basically I just created an Interceptor that catches ConstraintValidationExceptions at the appropriate tier and throws them forward as my own custom exceptions which are then properly serialized through CORBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced this problem to serialization of the ConstraintValidationException through CORBA. Somehow the bean-validation module is not loaded properly with osgi and the javax.validation.groups.Default class is missing. I made a quick workaround so that the ConstraintValidationException is intercepted and never sent through CORBA. Instead the validation error information is gathered in a custom Exception class that can be actually serialized through the services.